# Pushing Images Vaadin Java

Tags: image, websocket, vaadin, push, broadcast

i am trying to create a turn-base card game in Vaadin-Java, everything was going well so far, but i have a problem with pushing Vaadin Images to other UI. I did copy Broadcast/BroadcasterView Class from Vaadin Documentation and it works as intended, but not for images.

```
public class Broadcaster {
    static Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    static LinkedList<Consumer<String>> listeners = new LinkedList<>();

    public static synchronized Registration register(
            Consumer<String> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);

        return () -> {
            synchronized (Broadcaster.class) {
                listeners.remove(listener);
            }
        };
    }

    public static synchronized void broadcast(String message) {
        for (Consumer<String> listener : listeners) {
            executor.execute(() -> listener.accept(message));
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Push
@Route("broadcaster")
public class BroadcasterView extends Div {
    VerticalLayout messages = new VerticalLayout();
    Registration broadcasterRegistration;

    // Creating the UI shown separately

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        UI ui = attachEvent.getUI();
        broadcasterRegistration = Broadcaster.register(newMessage -> {
            ui.access(() -> messages.add(new Span(newMessage)));
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach(DetachEvent detachEvent) {
        broadcasterRegistration.remove();
        broadcasterRegistration = null;
    }
}
```

```
public BroadcasterView() {
    TextField message = new TextField();
    Button send = new Button("Send", e -> {
        Broadcaster.broadcast(message.getValue());
        message.setValue("");
    });

    HorizontalLayout sendBar = new HorizontalLayout(message, send);

    add(sendBar, messages);
}
```

the code above works fine for Strings, Vaadin Icons etc, but when i replace  for  and naturally change the broadcast method, there is no reaction.

i've searched for the solution throughout the internet, but it seems, people don't need to push images or it's simply not possible here. I thought that this is perhaps the matter of payload, but it doesn't work even for 5px x 5px images

perhaps one of You have encountered such problem and found solution?

Comment: Where is the code with dealing with the images? How do you access them from Vaadin?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass *data* through the broadcaster, but what you write about your attempts makes me suspect that you've been trying to pass *UI components* (i.e. instances of `com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image`). That won't work because a UI component instance cannot be attached to multiple locations (i.e. multiple browser windows in this case) at the same time.

What you can try is to pass the data (e.g. a String with the image URL) through the broadcaster and then let each subscriber create their own `Image` component based on the data that they receive.

Comment: wouldn't that also apply to Vaadin Icons? those work very well, whereas i cannot even create a new Image with ui.acces(()->)

Comment: It depends on how you use the icon. If you pass an icon constant such as `VaadinIcon.VAADIN_H`, then you're only passing a piece of data that identifies which icon to use, which should work. If you pass the result of e.g. `VaadinIcon.VAADIN_H.create()`, then you're passing an actual component instance, which shouldn't work.

Comment: When you say that you cannot create a new Image, then what exactly are the symptoms? Are there any error messages? Could it be that you're creating an image without a valid URL so that there's nothing to show in the browser?

Comment: actually i managed to push the image!!
instead of changing <brackets> from string to Image and put new Image in Broadcaster.broadcast() method, i left Strings be, but i added
ui.access(() -> board1.add(new Span()));
ui.access(() -> board1.add(dragImage)); // <--
and i still broadcast string! 
Thank You very much for Your interest!

Icons work a bit better and work even with <Icon> brackets in Broadcaster class and when i broadcast new Icon, but that doesn't matter to me much now.